# Trying to integrate Struts2 and Spring Security SAML with application using Java Configuration

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, spring-saml

I'm trying use the Spring Security SAML Extension with my application.  I'm having trouble figuring out the proper configuration.  In my application, I'm using Spring Java Configuration.  Here's my code:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ceiwc.es.config</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- For Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Handles Strut2 URL requests -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Mapping for Spring Security URLs -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Mapping for Struts2 URLs -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- /WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml -->
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> 
        /WEB-INF/spring/springSecurity-config.xml </param-value> </context-param> -->

    <!-- In charge of starting and stopping the Spring root ApplicationContext. 
        It also determines which configurations are to be used, by looking at the 
        contextConfigLocation. -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Here is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ceiwc.bc", "com.ceiwc.es"})
@Import({DataConfig.class, LdapConfig.class, CacheConfig.class})
@ImportResource({"/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml", "/WEB-INF/spring/springSecurity-config.xml"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:global.properties"})
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("iwmail.iwif-internal.com");
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I'm getting the following error:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
>     at
>   weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
>     at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
>     at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
>     at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

More stacktrace:

> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> User defined listener
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class.
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> Could not load user defined filter in web.xml:
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

What am I doing wrong?  If I add in the contextConfigLocation, I get an error indicating the DelegatingFilterProxy failed to initialize.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved this issue for me was adding the wls:prefer-web-inf-classes element and setting it to true.  A good explanation of this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/classloading.html).